# how to add $model for show pop html angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i am using below angularjs library in my project... i want to and $model its show error why i don't know

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js

below code does not run.. please help me

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$modal', function ($scope, $filter,$modal) {
              $scope.moreinformation = function (item) {
                                console.log('opening pop up');
                                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                                    templateUrl: 'popup.html',
                                    controller: 'myCtrl',
                                });
                            }

                }]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$modal` is a service included in [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), it is not a part of official angular library.

To use `$modal`, you have to include ui bootstrap in your page, then add it as your app dependency:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```